# Updating a value of a <span> using Javascript getElementById

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JS and trying to get my head around how to change values of a span using JS. So, I have a span looking like this:

```
<span id="s551392614400915" class="vote-count-post" value="551392614400915">0.31</span>
```

I would like to change the 0.31 to say 150 - and Iam trying to use the getElementById as follows:

```
var xx=150;
document.getElementById("s551392614400915").value = "150"; //dosent work.
//document.getElementById("s551392614400915").value = xx; //dosent work.
```

for some reason this does not seem to work. I know I am doing something completely stupid, but I am unable to see where. Here is my rather silly [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YnUbp/4/)

any help with this would be great.

Comment: `span` elements don't have `value` attributes

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementById("s551392614400915").innerHTML= "150"` if you want to change the contents of the `span`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this - wait going a bit crazy without knowing this!

Comment: Not sure why this answer is getting more upvotes? I posted my answer first... :P

Comment: I'm just cuter than a wrench :D

Comment: actually i posted 1st, but was waiting for 3 minutes delay

Comment: Hmm.. I guess we are at the mercy of sof's algorithm here

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `value`. `value` is used for form inputs with a user-changeable value.

```
document.getElementById("s551392614400915").innerHTML = "150";
```